# What plane is the Tarrasque from?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, planes

Lets say that the DM throws his super monster at you and it happens to be a Tarrasque. From what I was looking at it never really tells you what plane of existence they come from so in theory could you use [*banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) on it and just send it away to another plane of existence for them to deal with.

Does anyone know what plane the Tarrasque comes from, and can I use *banishment* on it for the full duration to banish it permanently?

Comment: And out of morbid curiosity, what level is your group?

Comment: Lol our DM tried something new he called it "The Fallen gods" we started of as level 15 and no gear. it was quite fun surprisingly, I thought it was just going to be us wrecking normal humans but he threw in some demi-gods and gods into the mixs.

Comment: The tarrasque is no joke. If your DM plays it right, it's one of the hardest things you can fight. My party went up against one at level 17/18, and we beat it mostly because the DM didn't play it optimally.

Comment: We had a big party of 6 people and we mostly just used longbows at max distance to weaken it, before we went in full force with our close up characters.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## You can try, but success is short lived (and you may be, too)

The Tarrasque (MM, 286) is a:

> monster of the Material Plane

Because of that, [*Banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) (Basic Rules, 217) can work, but you'll only have a minute until it comes back if you're fighting it on its home turf.

> If the target is native to the plane of existence you're on, you banish the target to a harmless demiplane. While there, the target is incapacitated. The target remains there until the spell ends, at which point the target reappears in the space it left or in the nearest unoccupied space if that space is occupied.

### Good chance it makes the save

But that's if it fails the save at all.

The Tarrasque has advantage on saves against magical effects, it has three uses of Legendary Resistance daily and can choose to make the save, and it's still got a +9 modifier to Charisma saves. Odds are it's making that save.

Answer (score 20):

On the page 286 of the *Monster Manual*, the opening line of the entry about [tarrasques](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-t#Tarrasque) states

> The legendary tarrasque is possibly the most dreaded monster of the Material Plane.

This means the tarrasque is not an extra-planar creature.